# Организация JS-кода на сайтах

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем привет!

Задача кратко: 
Как избавиться от лапшекода/спаггетти-кода/простыни кода.

---

Задача подробно:
Часто в js файлах можно увидеть такую картину: один файл, например main.js, в котором описано все что можно:

```
$(function() {
    $('#block').superPlugin();    
    $('#block2').plugin();    
    $('#block'3).supersuperPlugin();
    ...
    $('.close').click(function(){...});
    ...
    // и так еще 300 строчек кода
});
```

(Причем плагин *superPlugin* и *supersuperPlugin* используются на разных страницах.)

После применения паттернов типа *Module* или *PubSub* код становится лучше, но все же в одном файле остается лежать слишком много лишнего для одной страницы.

Так же не совсем понятно где инитить компоненты. Например, у меня есть конструктор **Filter**, который принимает класс элемента фильтра и блок контента, который перезагружается при выборе пункта фильтра.

На странице новостей я хочу один фильтр:

```
var newsFilter = new Filter('.news-filter', '.news-list');
```

А в каталоге другой:

```
var goodsFilter = new Filter('.goods-filter', '.goods-list');
```

Очевидно, что в один блоке кода им не место. Можно, конечно, добавить уникальный класс для body, типа news-page и catalog-page и через него разруливать, но это не айс, мне кажется:

```
if($(body).hasClass('.news-page'))
    var newsFilter = new Filter('.news-filter', '.news-list');
if($(body).hasClass('.catalog-page'))
    var goodsFilter = new Filter('.goods-filter', '.goods-list');
```

Поделитесь опытом, кто как справляется с такими проблемами? Стоит ли читать про AMD, что бы это не было? ))

---

Спасибо .)

Comment: для каждой страницы выводите данные типа:

     {
         pageFilters : [['.news-filter', '.news-list']]
     }

в итоге, достаточно сделать что-то типа:

    $(function() {
     var filters = PageInfo.pageFilters;
     if(filters) {
      $.each(filters, function(args){
        new (Filter.bind.apply(Filter, args));
      });
     }
    });

Причем где и как хранить эти данные дело ваше.

Comment: можно к body элемент data-filter прикрутить

Comment: @eicto, json в дата аттрибуты или как? :)

Comment: как хочется, хоть через запятую, split еще не отменили вроде.

Comment: @eicto, вам не кажется что это лишние сложности на ровном месте?

Comment: Извините, а это что?
{
     pageFilters : [['.news-filter', '.news-list']]
 }

Ну и фильты это ж только один из многих случаев, там еще может быть много строк кода.)

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus это json вашей конкретной страницы, естественно он может быть куда больше, в описанном мною примере предполагается, что вы будете выводить эти данные на сервере, что-то типа:

    <script>var PageInfo = {data}</script>

Ну и потом уже эти данные обрабатывать.

И да, вам нужно описывать и обрабатывать так каждый случай, хотя, конечно, выбор есть, можно продолжать писать спагетти код, это ваше дело.

@eicto, а в чем проблема к каждой странице приделать скрипт? Описанное решение придумано не мною и используется повсеместно, в том или ином виде, дата аттрибути менее общее решение

Comment: не вижу сложности,кода меньше вроде.

@psycho_Octopus ну если элементы разные и плагины разные и прочее, то никак не избавиться от перечисления. можно конечно и для общего случая написать, но это фреймворк получится в результате.

Comment: @AlexWindHope это bad paractice так делать - увеличивается размер каждого сгенереного файла (некэшируемого), баги появляются и прочее. лучше всего когда js в отдельных файлах весь и управляется разметкой.

Comment: А можно ссылку где про это более подробно написано? Потому что я пока не очень понял как мне это реализовать. Наверное, мне надо ткнуть что в какой файл писать, что бы я понял.)

Answer (score 4):

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) - если данные выносятся в отдельный скрипт (именно это я предлагал сделать), то я, хоть убей, не могу понять какое отношение это имеет к кешированию?

Причем тут баги, можно вот тут вот поподробнее?

Ну и напоследок - если это и bad practice, то почему-же таким подходом пользуется тот-же google, vk, facebook? Да и фраза bad practice от вас ничем не весомее чем фраза - good practice от меня :) В противном случае выглядит как "британские ученые доказали...".

Да, там есть вариации и редко можно увидеть настолько общее решение, насколько предложил я, нередко можно встретить что-то типа:

```
<script>
 require('someModule').init({ простыня json'a });
</script>
```

что, по сути, мало чем отличается от того, что предложил я. Так-же, нередко, таким образом реализовывается локализация (с дальнейшей подстановкой в клиентский шаблон). Или здесь вы тоже предлагаете использовать дата атрибуты?

Хотя, конечно, если сайт довольно простой и в нем не так много JS'a, то, возможно, лучше, действительно, обойтись дата атрибутами (KISS), но, судя по постановке вопроса, я сделал вывод, что речь идет, все-же, о сайте с большим количеством JS'a.

---

[[@psyсho_Octopus](/users/9600/psy%D1%81ho_octopus)](/users/9600/psy%D1%81ho_octopus) - все довольно просто, вам просто нужно разделять общую логику и логику инициализации, причем как именно это делать - решать вам. Это, в будущем, поможет вам с легкостью строить новые страницы и легко изменять старые, ну и, потенциально, при таком подходе, довольно легко реализовать администрирование, что-то типа настройка типов анимации, убрать добавить что-то и т.д. даже в случае если у вас single page app. К сожалению ссылок по теме не припомню.

Comment: Теперь вы и сами сможете :-) С возвращением!

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, но я все-равно не могу преобразовать свой ответ в комментарий, видимо можно преобразовывать только чужие ответы...

Comment: все довольно просто, вам просто нужно разделять общую логику и логику инициализации, причем как именно это делать - решать вам.
Это я и хочу узнать, ради этого и задал вопрос. Хотел получить конкретные примеры решения.)

Comment: @AlexWindHope: поскольку ваш комментарий настолько развёрнутый, я бы на вашем месте оставил его здесь в виде ответа для лучшей читаемости. Если хотите, я всё же попробую преобразовать в комментарий.

Comment: @VladD, хм, возможно вы правы.
****
@psyсho_Octopus, к сожалению, я не представляю как дать более развернутый ответ, кроме как предоставить шаблон приложения с использованием этого подхода, но это очень трудозатратно.

Comment: Хорошо. Но все равно, спасибо вам за ответы.)

Comment: ну примеры моего подхода можно встретить в bootstrap, насчет минусов вашего решения - подход который я предлагаю можно использовать для конкретных элементов (в данном случае блок контента наверное будет оптимально), универсальный js файл, а не вставка script посреди html,  кроме того вы предлагаете завести глобальную переменную, что тоже не есть гуд. для локализации можно использовать  data для указания локали (ru,en) и потом просто подгружать нужный файл опять-же одним и тем-же способом.

Comment: @eicto,

> подгружать нужный файл

При моем решении эти данные тоже можно подгружать и не держать в глобальной области видимости, но смысла в этом я не вижу. Более того, обычно в любом нормальном коде есть какой-то root namespace, таким образом, присвоив эти данные пропертей этого объекта мы избавимся от глобальной переменной.

И еще, по поводу подгружать файл локализации, это намного медленее, это раз и два - вы все-равно будете его где-то хранить в памяти после загрузки, зачем заставлять пользователя ждать и мудрить с дата атрибутами в этом случае мне не понятно

Answer (score 0):

Мой Вам совет. Насчет модульности и всего прочего - посмотрите на [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). Он достаточно сложен для понимания, особенно если переходить на него с jQuery, но он позволяет делать все те вещи, о которых Вы говорите и даже больше. =)